# flashsocket.io or socket.io with flex app + externalinterfaces

Tags: apache-flex, socket.io, externalinterface

I currently have a `flex application` which is a `simple chat` and it does long polling.
I wanted to improve this by using `sockets`.

I also used flex `LCCS(server pushing)` after long polling and later realized that LCCS is going to be closed soon, so I moved on to using socket.io

I see two options,

1. Using [socket.io](http://socket.io) in js and communicating it with flex app using externalinterfaces
2. Using [flashsocket.io](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO)

I did implement the second case (externalinterfaces + js socket)in my application, but I do see that 1 out of 10 is a failure.

By failure i mean, the application runs into an error condition like

1. either the node server does not reply back (weird)
2. flex application does not perform io.connect('server') successfully.

> So i was wondering if changing this to **flashsocket.io** is a better option or not ?

Kindly suggest and if this is a possible duplicate please point me to it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in Producer/Consumer functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an application based on Flex 4/Node.js and we are using flashsocket (with a little modification). And I would say we are pretty happy with it. If you want I can share the updated Flashsocket with you.

I avoided the first approach as to why use ExternalInterface/JS while all can be done using flex/flash only.